# Can't set title on UIViewController subclass

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller

I'm having the following problem.

I've created a custom view controller that has a some useful methods that I need.

This is the code in the .h

```
@interface MYViewController : UIViewController

- (void)method;
- (void)otherMethod;

@end
```

This is my init method of MYViewController class:

```
- (instancetype)init
{
    self = [super init];

    return self;
}
```

Then when I try to extend that class I can't set the title of the child controller. For example, in "MYOtherController.h"

```
@interface MYOtherViewController : MYViewController

- (void)childControllerMethod;

@end
```

And this is the init of MYOtherViewController:

```
- (instancetype)init
{
    self = [super init];

    return self;
}
```

And then, if I instantiate a MYOtherViewController object and try to set the title, it happens nothing. For example:

```
MYOtherViewController *controller = [[MYOtherViewController] alloc] init];
controller.title = @"Hello";
```

If I put this in the viewDidLoad of the MYOtherViewController class it logs that title is nil:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    NSLog(@"title: %@", self.title);
    [super viewDidLoad];
}
```

Why can't set the title in this child class?

Answer (score 0):

the title for the viewcontroller hasnt been made yet after the alloc init, you would need to set it after the viewDidLoad (which is when all the UI elements have been initialized), so what you can do is make an `@property` on the viewcontroller which you set after the alloc init, then in the viewDidLoad, set the title to the value of the `@property`